# PHP remove last zero from integer by substr

Tags: php

in php i get some values from database as integer, now i want to remove last zero from `20000000` integer, but me below code doesnt work.

```
$payerd_amount = 20000000;
$payerd_amount = substr((string)$payerd_amount,1,strlen((string)$payerd_amount) -1);
```

how to do this action? my code seems correct but after substring i get this result:

```
000
```

Comment: Why not just divide by `10`?

Comment: @zerkms your solution doesnt work for all integers.

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy If it ends with zero then it sure does

Comment: "your solution doesnt work for all integers" --- this statement makes no sense.

Comment: @lbu can you remove last zero for this integer: `13520` by divide by 10??????

Comment: You sure can. What do you think will be `13520 / 10`?

Comment: @ibu left stackoverflow for good.

Comment: @lbu . yes thats right. i'm sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is remove the last zero, just divide by 10

```
   $payerd_amount = $payerd_amount / 10;
```

This works, too:

```
   $payerd_amount = substr($payerd_amount, 0, -1);
```

Answer (score 3):

If it does not work on all integers to just devide by 10, it probably is because of rounding?
So...

```
$newint = floor($payerd_amount / 10);
// if the number is 123456, newint will be 12345
```

Comment: @Hanky The reason to floor it is to make sure the number does not become a float. With or without a zero it works. As he said "divide with 10 does not work on all integer". Which is true if it's not a 0 as the last digit. Because if it is a say 5, the integer becomes a float. Thus it does not work on all integers. See?

Comment: @HankyPanky If that was the case, that we do not teach mathematics here, then there are loads of threads that should be locked. I answered his question with a way to keep an integer an integer with math. Like it or not, it works on (almost) all number.

Answer (score 1):

You can start from 0 replace with 1. Example

```
$payerd_amount = 20000000;
$payerd_amount = substr((string)$payerd_amount,0,strlen((string)$payerd_amount) -1);
print($payerd_amount);
```

Output

```
2000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$payerd_amount = substr($payerd_amount, 0, -1);
```

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)